# TypeError Controller.extend is not a function

Tags: sapui5

When running my project, I am getting:

> Error: failed to load 'stock/controller/plant.controller.js' from ./controller/plant.controller.js: TypeError: Controller.extend is not a function

Please, let me know how to fix it.

## plant.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "jquery.sap.global",
    "stock/Formatter",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (jQuery, Formatter, Controller, History, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    var TableController =  Controller.extend("stock.controller.plant", {
        onInit: function () {
            var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.mock", "/products.json"));
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        },

        getRouter : function () {
            return sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        },

        onNavBack: function (oEvent) {
            var oHistory = History.getInstance();
            var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
            if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
                window.history.go(-1);
            } else {
                this.getRouter().navTo("input", {}, true /*no history*/);
            }
        }
    });
    return TableController;
});
```

## Component.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(UIComponent, JSONModel, XMLView) {
    "use strict";

    var Component = UIComponent.extend("stock.Component", {
        metadata: {
            manifest: "json",
            getTable: function () {
                return this._rootView.getContent()[0];
            }
        },
        publicMethods: [
            "getTable"
        ],
        dependencies: {
            libs: [
                "sap.m",
                "sap.ui.layout"
            ]
        },
        rootView: "stock.view.input",
        config: {
            sample: {
                files: [
                    "view.input.view.xml",
                    "controller.main.controller.js",
                    "Formatter.js"
                ],
                description : "In this example assisted input is provided with table-like suggestions where several columns can display more details."
            }
        },

        init : function () {
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
            this.getRouter().initialize();
        }
    });

    Component.prototype.createContent = function () {
        this._rootView = sap.ui.xmlview({ viewName : "stock.view.plant" });
        return this._rootView;
    };

    return Component;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You overlooked the sequence of the files declaration. In your example you use a "stock/Formatter" file as a "Controller", which is obviously wrong. Below is a correct sequence:

```
sap.ui.define([
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'stock/Formatter',
        'sap/ui/core/routing/History',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
    ], function (Controller, jQuery, Formatter, History,JSONModel) {
});
```

Comment: Now i can only view the second view(plant.view.xml)...but i want to navigate from my first view(input.view.xml) to second view which was happening initially.Can you please suggest how can i display first view(input.view.xml) first and then navigate from that.I have added component.js in my previous post.Please let me know if you need any other code snippet for providing some help.

Comment: Considering what you shown in your question, it seems that you use a kind of strange app/component configuration. You should check it out in the ui5 documentation.